# Friend, private function, template alias, and decltype... is clang correct in rejecting this?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, friend

In the following code ([godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/uy-zVs)):

```
#include <utility>

struct Friend {
    class Inner {
        friend struct Friend;

        int function() { return 0; }
    };

    using DirectResult = decltype(std::declval<Inner>().function());

    template <typename T>
    using IndirectResult = decltype(std::declval<T>().function());
};

int main() {
    Friend::DirectResult direct{};
    Friend::IndirectResult<Friend::Inner> indirect{};
    return direct + indirect;
}
```

Clang is perfectly happy with the use of `DirectResult`, but will complaing that `IndirectResult` is attempting to access a `private` function of `Inner`:

```
<source>:13:55: error: 'function' is a private member of 'Friend::Inner'    
    using IndirectResult = decltype(std::declval<T>().function());
                                                      ^
<source>:18:13: note: in instantiation of template type alias 'IndirectResult' requested here
    Friend::IndirectResult<Friend::Inner> indirect{};
            ^
```

I would have expected the access to be fine, as the template alias is declared within the friend class.

However, in my experience Clang is generally right (more so than gcc) when it comes to interpreting the C++ standard.

**Is Clang correct in rejecting this code?** And if so, what am I missing?

*Note: gcc 7.x, 8.x, and 9.x accept the code.*

Comment: @cigien: Thanks for the edit, I was looking for that [tag:language-lawyer] tag and could not remember the name.

Comment: No problem. This should get the attention of people who know this stuff :)

Comment: Note: changing `IndirectResult` to `decltype(function(std::declval<T>()))` where `function` is a private function of `Friend` compiles successfully... so the `friend` appears necessary to trigger the issue.

Comment: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=25334

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: This is likely the very same issue indeed. It was reported nearly 5 years ago (May 2015), so I am disappointed that there are no updates as to whether it should be legal or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [a bug](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=25334) in Clang. Per [**[class.friend]/2**](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.friend#2):

> Declaring a class to be a friend implies that the names of private and protected members from the class granting friendship can be accessed in the base-specifiers and member declarations of the befriended class.

Per [**[class.mem]**](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem), a *template-declaration* can be a *member-declaration*, and per [**[temp.pre]/2.5**](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.pre#2.5) an *alias-declaration* can be the *declaration* in a *template-declaration*. So a member alias template has access to the private and protected members of the class's friends.

Fortunately, the bug appears only to apply to the *defining-type-id* of an *alias-declaration*; you can work around it by moving the computation into a helper class (with nested `type` alias), or more concisely to a *default template-argument*:

```
template <typename T, class U = decltype(std::declval<T>().function())>
using IndirectResult = U;
```