# Template type alias visibility compiler disagreement

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

The following example compiles with gcc but not with clang. Which compiler is right, and why?

```
#include <utility>

struct Foo {

private:
    
    template<typename T>
    static int f();

public:

    template<typename U>
    using T = decltype(f<U>());

};


int main () {

    static_assert(std::is_same_v<Foo::T<float>, int>);
}
```

Clang complains that `'f' is a private member of 'Foo'`. I think this is not correct as `f` is accessed from within `Foo` and thus should be visible. Interestingly, it works if `T` is not a template.

Live code [here](https://godbolt.org/z/nq8hMW).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [clang bug](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=25334), where clang doesn't resolve the correct access control for names used in member alias templates.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61410959/friend-private-function-template-alias-and-decltype-is-clang-correct-in-re) is an example of the bug, where the access control for names of members of friend classes is resolved incorrectly.

In your example, you have a static member template `f`, and for that we only need [temp.mem#2](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.mem#2)

> ... Access control rules apply to member template names. ...

So `f` is indeed visible in the declaration of `T`, and the code is valid.

Note that the fix mentioned in the linked post works here as well, since it's the same bug:

```
template<typename U, typename X = decltype(f<U>())>
using T = X;  // ok
```